# Can't craft valid IAM SSL Certificate for Cloudfront

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, pem, amazon-iam

I created a CSR by running the good ole

```
$ openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout example.key -out example.csr
```

This yielded an example.csr and example.key

Then, I got it signed and received back 4 .crt files. My domain .crt, 2 intermediates, and the root.

From this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_UploadServerCertificate.html, I gather that Amazon wants that my private-key be PEM encoded, so I ran

```
$ openssl rsa -in example.key -text > example.pem
```

Cloudfront also wants what they call a CertificateChain, and from https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/setting-up-ssl-on-aws-cloudfront-and-s3/ and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html#SampleCert, it seems that the file should be the 2 intermediate certs concatenated together. So I made that file using a text editor and called it example.crt.chain

Finally, with all that in hand, I ran

```
$ aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name star-assets-example-com --certificate-body file://STAR_assets_example_com.crt --private-key file://example.pem --certificate-chain file://example.crt.chain --path /cloudfront/assets/
```

That returned to me the "ServerCertificateMetadata". Finally, I went to the Cloudfront console and tried to set that certificate as the "Custom SSL Certificate" for cloudfront. But, it tells me that

```
AWS Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate, AWS Error Message: The specified SSL certificate doesn't exist in the IAM certificate store, isn't valid, or doesn't include a valid certificate chain.
```

**Modifications I have tried.**

1. Including and not including the root certificate in the chain. Both upload but neither work.
2. I have tried removing the "modulus", "privateExponent", "prime1", etc from the head of my PEM file so that it only contains the "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" stuff, like the AWS article suggests. Both upload but neither work.
3. Changing the ordering of certificates in my chain file results in an invalid error from the uploader tool.
4. Not including the certificate chain, but that clearly goes against what cloudfront says I need.
5. Using my original example.key file instead of the `openssl rsa` encoded PEM file. That produces errors from the uploader tool. This file is of the form "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So it turns out that my error was simply that my certificate size was too long. The maximum length is 2048, while mine was 4096! I found my issue by reading about similar issue here [Having trouble associated SSL cert with Amazon Cloudfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537498/having-trouble-associated-ssl-cert-with-amazon-cloudfront?rq=1)

I guess that's what the obscure 'invalid' meant. I *really* wish there was more validation with better error messages!!!!

Comment: Did you have to buy a whole new certificate? I just ran into the same problem.

Comment: I think you can usually get your SSL certificate provider to re-sign a new Certificate Signing Request (CSR) with the new length

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error, however it turns out that I needed to upload the certificate chain from the issuer as well.  Here is the final command that I ran.

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name <name> --certificate-body file://domain.crt --private-key file://domain.key  --certificate-chain file://issuer.cer --path /cloudfront/
```

Answer (score 0):

Also got this error, and spent more time than I'd like trying to work out why it was failing (key size over 2048, cert chain etc).

I was attempting to use an IAM cert when creating the distribution through Terraform (specifying [iam_certificate_id](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_distribution.html#iam_certificate_id)). Having looked at the AWS web interface for creating a distribution, there's no option to enter IAM cert Id, and it appears to only allow ACM certs. Did support once exist for IAM certificates (as [Terraform aws_cloudfront_distribution](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_distribution.html#iam_certificate_id) includes it) but has now been dropped (as not available on AWS console)?

When using ACM cert instead of IAM cert it worked fine for me.