# Performance Implications of 4096-bit SSL Certificates

Tags: performance, ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8453915/2847723) that says, it makes sites load slower.

> Pretty much all* browsers will support 4096-bit keys. The issue you'll run into is that key exchange is slower with larger keys, which will increase load on the server and slow down page loading on the client.

I recently installed a 4096-bit certificate and like to know some real word numbers and benchmarks to know if this was a bad decision.

Comment: It will slow down the certificate-related parts of the SSL handshake, but provided you have SSL session resumption in place it won't have any further effect until the session expires.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Its about performance not security but its about SSL so mods can move it if they want.